# Cannot connect to my site with apache over port 81

Tags: virtualhost, port, apache2

I have two sites and I want to run them in the same IP but in different ports with Apache. I modified ports.conf file as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:81
Listen 81
```

and the 000-default file in sites-enabled is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName site-1.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site/httpdocs/HTML/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/site/httpdocs/HTML>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    <files xmlrpc.php>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
    </files>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName site-2.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
       Options FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The netstat command outputs the following:

```
sudo netstat -tlpn | grep apache
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6492/apache2    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:81              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6492/apache2
```

While every time I restart the server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Concerning the firewall I try the following:

```
sudo ufw allow 81
```

and

```
sudo ufw disabe
```

Unfortunately, When I run the ip of my server in 80 port everything is working but when I run the ip with 81 port the browser cannot connect.

Also I try to run the second virtualhost in 80 port the everything is working.

I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: How do you try to open the web page when served on port 81? Why are you trying to server HTTP on port 81?

Comment: Through a browser (firefox and chrome) with the HTTP protocol. For example: http ://ip:81 . I chose to run two sites in different ports because I don't have domain names and I run them with the IP of the machine. So in order Apache to differentiate the sites I use the different ports.

Comment: Your config looks ok, the server is listing. Did you try with curl or telnet to connect via localhost port 81 and got a response? Is the firewall really disabled (iptables -L)? Do you have a HTTP proxy configured in your browser or OS? Can you make a portscan from outside the machine or at least do the curl/wget/telnet trick from your client machine? Did you try with http://site-2.example.com:81 instead of http://ip:81/?